# Replicating IsNullable(of T) Value accessing

Tags: vb.net, nullable

When using Nullable(Of T) you can access its value by either calling Nullable(Of T).Value property directly, or by just accessing the object directly eg:

```
    Dim myValue As Nullable(Of Integer) = 10

    Debug.WriteLine(myValue.Value)
    Debug.WriteLine(myValue)
```

How would I replicate the second example in my own class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write implicit conversion operators for your type and the type you wish to convert to/from.

This is done using the [`Widening`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz3wbx3x.aspx) or [`Narrowing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w127ed2.aspx) modifiers.

See the [Type Conversions in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcb26cc8.aspx) topic on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
If(myValue.HasValue, myValue.Value, 0)
```

So if there is no value, we take `0` (or whatever is suitable for you) as a default.